# Phonegap : layout breaks when keyboard is shown

Tags: javascript, html, ios, twitter-bootstrap, cordova

I am experiencing UI issues when the keyboard is opened. When the keyboard is opened,style of all the elements having `position : fixed` breaks. They appear to be scrolling with the content. Please help me to fix this problem.

The issue exists in iOS 6.1, 7.1

Answer (score 0):

As per **[documentation link](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/guide_platforms_ios_config.md.html)** of phonegap build version 3.1, we need to use **"KeyboardShrinksView"** preferences in config.xml. Set to true to scale down the webview when the keyboard appears, overriding the default beavior that shrinks the viewport vertically. This matches the default behaviour for Android apps.

`<preference name="KeyboardShrinksView" value="true"/>`

Good luck!